# I can't grab region or region_id in Admin Controller - Magento 1.7

Tags: customer, shipping, address, billing

I grab the customer through their email in a backend controller:

```
$baseCustomer = $customerModel->loadByEmail($creationEmail);
```

Then I grab $customer['default_billing'] to get the ID of the billing address information.

```
    $cloneBilling = $baseCustomer['default_billing'];
    $baseAddress = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($cloneBilling);
```

From there I'm able to grab the customers firstname, lastname, street, city, postcode, country_id, and telephone.

```
$cloneCountryId = $baseAddress['country_id'];
        $clonePostcode = $baseAddress['postcode'];
        $cloneCity = $baseAddress['city'];
        $cloneTelephone = $baseAddress['telephone'];
        $cloneStreet = $baseAddress['street'];
```

TLDR Question: I have the customer and they have an address how do I grab the region and region_id also known as the state?

Comment: have you tried `$baseAddress['region']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `Mage_Customer_Model_Address_Abstract::getRegion()`, you'll notice that underlying it is actually a model. In your case, try

```
$baseAddress->getRegion(); // returns string, eg. Texas
$baseAddress->getRegionId(); // returns numeric, eg. 57
$baseAddress->getRegionModel(); // returns Mage_Directory_Model_Country 
$baseAddress->getRegionCode(); // returns string, eg. TX
```

[edit]
My test code:

```
$m = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load(14);
$result[] = $m->getData();
$result[] = $m->getRegionId();
$result[] = $m->getRegion();
$result[] = $m['region'];
```

Here's the `$result`:

`array(4) {
  [0] => array(23) {
    ["entity_id"] => string(2) "14"
    ["entity_type_id"] => string(1) "2"
    ["attribute_set_id"] => string(1) "0"
    ["increment_id"] => NULL
    ["parent_id"] => string(2) "23"
    ["created_at"] => string(25) "2013-01-25T11:35:28+08:00"
    ["updated_at"] => string(19) "2013-02-18 03:11:19"
    ["is_active"] => string(1) "1"
    ["prefix"] => NULL
    ["firstname"] => string(9) "Collage02"
    ["middlename"] => NULL
    ["lastname"] => string(4) "test"
    ["suffix"] => NULL
    ["company"] => NULL
    ["city"] => string(9) "Putrajaya"
    ["country_id"] => string(2) "MY"
    ["region"] => string(9) "WP Labuan"
    ["postcode"] => string(5) "72510"
    ["telephone"] => string(10) "0375216584"
    ["fax"] => NULL
    ["vat_id"] => NULL
    ["region_id"] => string(3) "500"
    ["street"] => string(9) "Presint 6"
  }
  [1] => int(500)
  [2] => string(12) "WP Putrajaya"
  [3] => string(12) "WP Putrajaya"
}`

One reason the region info is empty could be that it is empty. You can check it by looking at the result of `print_r($baseAddress->getData());`

Comment: getRegion() returns nothing. getRegionId() returns 0?